# What is meant by $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle ^H_\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

there is the following statement:

Let $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle_\mathbb{R} = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} x_k y_k$ be that standard Euclidian scalar product in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle_\mathbb{C} = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} x_k \overline{w_k}$ be the standard hermitical scalar product on $\mathbb{C}^n$. Prove or falsify $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle_\mathbb{R}^H = \langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle_\mathbb{C}$.
Where $\langle z,w \rangle^H = \langle x+iy,u+iv \rangle^H := \langle x,u \rangle + \langle y,v \rangle - i(\langle x,v \rangle - \langle y,u \rangle)$ is a Hermitical scalar product on $\mathbb{C}^n$ for $x,y,u,v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with an Euclidian scalar product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

My problem now is that I don't really know what they mean by $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle_\mathbb{R}^H $. Do I have to apply $\langle z,w \rangle^H$ on the standard Eucledian scalar product? Do I have to transform that standard scalar product into the form of $\langle z,w \rangle^H$ and see that it is just the standard hermitian (if the statement is actually true)? I've tried both approaches by now but did not come to anything useful yet. Maybe I am on the wrong path?

Thank you very much for your help.

FunkyPeanut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It denotes a scalar product on a vector space of pairs of vectors. On these pairs of vectors a scalar multiplication with complex numbers is defined. You have, essentially, to show that the defined scalar product is compatible with the multiplication with complex numbers, linear in the first and anti-linear in the second argument.

---

Generalized, a $\Bbb R$ vector space $V$ with some scalar product $⟨⋅,⋅⟩$ is given. Now define $V^H=V\times V$ with scalar multplication with complex numbers defined as
$$
(a+ib)(v,w)=(av-bw,bv+aw)
$$
and a scalar product as in the task,
$$
⟨x+iy,u+iv⟩^H:=⟨x,u⟩+⟨y,v⟩−i(⟨x,v⟩−⟨y,u⟩)
$$
Now show that
$$
⟨(a+ib)(x+iy),u+iv⟩^H=(a+ib)⟨x+iy,u+iv⟩^H=⟨x+iy,(a-ib)(u+iv)⟩^H
$$
where you can only use linearity over the real numbers as a known property.